# Xamarin - Visual Studio - Android compile version not present despite being installed

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-manager

I have run both the sdkmanager command line, and the SDK Manager throuhg Visual Studio to add 28 but still it will not show in my properties in Visual Studio.

[image]

If I manually change it in the .csproj, I get:

> Project [PROJECT] cannot build using TargetFrameworkVersion v9.0 because it s not supported. Please change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is supported.

What am I missing?  How can I get Visual Studio/Xamarin to recognize that it is installed?

Comment: I didn't install SDK Platform 28 but I can choose it as Target Framework. Did you check VS for updates?

Comment: I do need an update, I will give that a try

Comment: Hey, were you able to find a solution? I have the same problem on Visual Studio 2019 (just released)

Comment: I don't remember what I had done, it involved installing the newest version of something... dammit, sorry, I wish I had recorded it - I forgot this was up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
please follow this link may it help you
```

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129245/project-xyz-droid-cannot-build-using-targetframework-v8-1-because-it-is-not-supported-error